# Not able to capture 4 way handshake using airodump-ng

Tags: handshake, airodump-ng

I am not able capture 4 way handshake, I also tried manually disconnecting and reconnecting my device to the network in hope that airodump-ng will capture the handshake but no luck. I checked the device was successfully getting disconnected after sending deauthentication packets, and gets automatically reconnected the moment I stop sending the packets. I am using Kali 2020.2 in VirtualBox. My Wifi adapter is TP-Link TL-WN722N(V3) with Realtek rtl8188eus chipset. Also one weird thing I noticed, deauthentication attacks do not work everytime, it only works roughly 1 out of 5 times and discovering networks around me take 30-40 seconds. I tried reinstalling VirtualBox and Kali Linux, still no improvement.

*Commands that I am using*

- airodump-ng --bssid (bssid of router) --channel (channel number) --write handshk wlan0
- aireplay-ng --deauth 32 -a (bssid of router) -c (target client) wlan0

I can see the captured packets in handshk.cap file but no handshake is being detected by aircrack-ng.

Result of aircrack-ng

```
root@kali:~# aircrack-ng handshk-01.cap -w test.txt

Reading packets, please wait...
Opening handshk-01.cap
Read 2180918 packets.


       BSSID                 ESSID               Encryption

1 (bssid of router)   (name of the network)   WPA (0 handshake)


Choosing first network as target.


Reading packets, please wait...
Opening handshk-01.cap
Read 2180918 packets.


1 potential targets


Packets contained no EAPOL data; unable to process this AP.




Quitting aircrack-ng...
```

Comment: I always ask, is anything else manipulating your interface's channel during the capture?

Comment: @multithr3at3d Yes, I have killed all the proccess by `airmon-ng check kill` command.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running Kali in a VirtualBox, it's possible that your host OS is communicating with either directly with the USB network adapter, or with other USB devices on the same bus.  It's also possible that your VM is being interrupted by the host OS at critical times in the communication protocol.

Running `airmon-ng check kill` can only check if you are running other processes in the Kali VM that may interfere with it.  But it cannot prevent your host computer from running similar processes that interfere with it.

Try running Kali natively on the computer, using a Kali Live Boot image from a USB stick (https://www.kali.org/get-kali/#kali-live).